# Max and min assignment giving incorrect and inconsistent values

Tags: python

Im struggling to fix my code for a prompted assignment. Sometimes it gives the correct answers, other times it doesn't. For whatever reason, the input "12, 18, 4, 9" gives a max of 12?

```py
def max_number(num1, num2, num3, num4):
    if (num1 > (num2 and num3 and num4)):
        return num1
    elif (num2 > (num3 and num4)):
        return num2
    elif num3>num4:
        return num3
    else:
        return num4
    
    
def min_number(num1, num2, num3, num4):
    if num1<(num2 and num3 and num4):
        return num1
    elif num2<(num3 and num4):
        return num2
    elif num3<num4:
        return num3
    else:
        return num4
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num1 = int(input())
    num2 = int(input())
    num3 = int(input())
    num4 = int(input())
    print('Maximum is', max_number(num1, num2, num3, num4))
    print('Minimum is', min_number(num1, num2, num3, num4))
```

Comment: Just glancing at this, do you mistake `and` for addition? And is just a boolean operator. That is to say `2 and 1` will return 1.

Comment: Hint: what exactly do you expect `(num2 and num3 and num4)` to mean by itself? What do you expect to happen if you compare *the result of that* to `num1`? Because that is necessarily what happens; you cannot make the `<` "distribute" across the `and`s.

Comment: That said: `max` and `min` are built in. What exactly is the intent of this code?

Comment: Thank you all for the help! It was a class project that required we worked around all of the built-in information. I'm very new to programming so I appreciate the feedback and guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the syntax you're looking for:

```
def min_number(num1, num2, num3, num4):
    if num1 < num2 and num1 < num3 and num1 < num4:
        return num1
    elif num2 < num3 and num2 < num4:
        return num2
    elif num3<num4:
        return num3
    else:
        return num4
```

`and` is a bool compare when used in an if statement like this, it doesn't chain if statements as  I think you believe. In other words each statement in between the `and` needs to be complete, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers offered which touch on the behavior of `and` when used with two integers, you may also wish to calculate whether a value is less than all of another set of numbers using something like:

```
all(num1 < n for n in [num2, num3, num4])
```

Or checking to see that `num1` is greater than `num2`, `num3`, and `num4`:

```
all(num1 > n for n in [num2, num3, num4])
```

Comment: This is a nice, clean way of solving the problem. However I think that comprehensions might be a bit above his head atm... @glow check out python list comprehension if you want to understand what is happening here, this would be a very "pythonic" way of achieving what you want.

Comment: What's shown here are related to list comprehensions, but are actually "generator expressions."

Comment: Will do that for sure! I appreciate the specific guidance!!

Comment: Chris, Good point. @glow There is actually a good example/explanation here that I just found: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/ About halfway through "Rationale" they give an example of min/max/sum.